# How do I backup, preferably automatically, my Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS system on another drive?

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, backup, encryption, 22.04

I have 3 drives:

- my main 500GB SSD drive w/Ubuntu,
- my secondary 250GB SSD drive w/Windows 10,
- and my extra 1TB HDD w/no OS.

I am hoping to have an automatic or semi automatic method of backing up both my SSD drives on the HDD.
I have just upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.
I keep my Ubuntu natively encrypted (ie, I use the option to encrypt during install).

I was hoping that the "Backup" option on 22.04.1 LTS would allow me the option of using another drive (instead of the cloud or local file) but that doesn't look like it's possible.

Comment: another drive = local file. make the file be on the other drive.

Comment: Since you want to backup windows too why not `dd` both partitions and store them on the hdd using a timestamp in the outputfile? It is not a good idea to backup windows system files outside of windows though. Same goes for Linux. It is cheaper and better to only backup personal files. If you do that for Linux I would use `rsync`.

Comment: First mount your HDD (Another drive) automatically at boot. The partition is mounted at a "mount point" which is a local folder in your Ubuntu SSD. Then select backup location as a local folder > the mount point of the HDD partition.

Comment: @Rinzwind If I do mount the other HDD automatically at boot, does that mean that I can't use the rest of the HDD for the windows SSD?

Comment: @user68186 I am not sure how to "dd both partitions and store them using a timestamp in the output file"  I was thinking that I would store a complete mirror or restore point that would exactly replicate what I have on the other 2.

Comment: @Esther  Thanks for the comments.  I am not sure how I could "make the file be on the other drive".  Do I first format the drive?  Do I use a specific type of path?  They are not partitions but different drives entirely.

Comment: you mount the drive, and it shows up like a directory in your filesystem. Then you can put the backup files in that directory. Linux doesn't really care if it's a different partition or drive, it treats all storage locations like they are part of one file hierarchy tree.

Answer (score 1):

You can create images of both your drives on HDD. Probably the simplest method is to use [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/). You need to burn a Clonezilla live DVD or USB, boot from it and tell it to backup both your SSD drives to the HDD. Your "main" drive will be probably named `/dev/sda`, your "secondary" drive `/dev/sdb` and the HDD will appear as `/dev/sdc` and you'll probably want to save your images on partition `/dev/sdc1`.

When you need to restore the backup, again you have to boot from Clonezilla live DVD/USB and restore the image(s).

However, I'm not sure how well Clonezilla deals with encrypted partitions as I have never tried that. In case Clonezilla fails,
you can also do the backup the old-fashioned way using `dd` command. However, this copies your whole disk, so probably will copy a lot of unnecessary "empty" space and take a long time. Again I assume your "main 500 GB SSD drive" is `/dev/sda` and your "secondary 250 GB SSD drive" is `/dev/sdb`. Boot from the live Ubuntu DVD/USB and click on your HDD icon. It will be mounted as something like `/media/ubuntu/somename`. Then type the commands:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/media/ubuntu/somename/maindisk.img bs=1M
```

(this will take a **long** time and create a 500 GB file `maindisk.img` on your HDD that is the image of your main disk)

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=/media/ubuntu/somename/secdisk.img bs=1M
```

(this will do the same for your secondary drive, creating a 250 GB file `secdisk.img` on your HDD)

If you ever need to restore the backup, you run the same commands in reverse direction:

```
sudo dd if=/media/ubuntu/somename/maindisk.img of=/dev/sda bs=1M
```

or

```
sudo dd if=/media/ubuntu/somename/secdisk.img of=/dev/sdb bs=1M
```

Be aware that these commands will UNCONDITIONALLY OVERWRITE your whole "main" or "secondary" disk with the contents of the image file!

Comment: Thanks a bunch.  I will try Clonezilla.  I know it differs based on sys specs but when you say long, do you mean an hr, hours, or a day or what?  I have a Ryzen 5 3600 16GB sys.  The mirror will keep all my settings such as the vpn, printer, gnome tweaks where as if I just keep my private files, I will have to re-remember what I did.

Comment: I think `dd` will take several hours.